# how to find the length of a set?

Tags: java, android, set

I'm trying to find the lentgh of a set from a preference.
I tired set.length, but it doesnt work. Anyone know another way to find a length of a set?

```
   set = prefs.getStringSet("key", null);
            int X = set.length; //it doesn't like length....
```

Comment: Did you even consider looking at the Javadocs?

Comment: Searched for "java get length of set" and this was the first link.

Comment: @PandemoniumSyndicate So?

Answer (score 33):

I believe instead of set.length, you'll want to call `set.size()`

Answer (score 7):

Your set is a `Set<String>`, not a `String[]`. So you have to call:

```
int x = set.size();
```